# Incoming sms listener on blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i've used below code for notify the sms .

Its working on **two blackberry simulator**.

I've install  the app on my device and send sms from android device.

The sms listener not working on device.

Incoming message received on device. but my app not notify the listener .

What is the problem how to resolve it.

What **port number** need to give for device?

```
class BackgroundApplication extends Application  implements MessageListener
{  
    int i=0;
    static String suffix;
    MessageConnection _mc ;

    public BackgroundApplication() 
    {
        try {
            _mc = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://:0");
            _mc.setMessageListener(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


    }

public void notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection conn) {
        try {

            Message m = _mc.receive();
            String address = m.getAddress();
            String msg = null;
            if ( m instanceof TextMessage )
            {
                TextMessage tm = (TextMessage)m;
                msg = tm.getPayloadText();
            }
            else if (m instanceof BinaryMessage) {
                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                byte[] data = ((BinaryMessage) m).getPayloadData();

                // convert Binary Data to Text
                msg = new String(data, "UTF-8");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Invalid Message Format");
            System.out.println("Received SMS text from " + address + " : " + msg);
            showDialog("Msg: "+msg);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }


    private void showDialog(String string) {


        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) 
        {
            Status.show(""+string,Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.INFORMATION), 5000,
                    Status.GLOBAL_STATUS, true, false, 1);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @Signare hi need to change port no 0 to 6222?

Comment: wt port number need to give?

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-listen-for-SMS-messages/ta-p/445062

```
DatagramConnection _dc =
     (DatagramConnection)Connector.open("sms://");
            for(;;)
        {
               Datagram d = _dc.newDatagram(_dc.getMaximumLength());
               _dc.receive(d);
               byte[] bytes = d.getData();
               String address = d.getAddress();
               String msg = new String(bytes);
               System.out.println( "Received SMS text from " + address + " : " + msg);
         }
```